# ¿Cual es la diferencia de uso de getRange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Veo que en google apps script hay dos formas de obtener el rango de celdas de una tabla:

Por letras

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C3");
```

O por indice

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 3, 3);
```

Ambos codigos me van a devolver la informacion que este en el rango de celdas de A1 a C3. He buscado pero no he encontrado documentación que explique mas a detalle la diferencia entre las dos formas .
La primera forma es mas intuitiva,pero quisiera saber para que tipo de situaciones es util la segunda forma.

Comment: Eso viene de VBA en Excel. Allá también se puede jugar con los rangos así. 

Sobre el posible uso que se le puede dar, eso está basado en opiniones y hará que te cierren la pregunta. Como comentario, podrías pensar en una macro o código que recorra filas de acuerdo a un contador i que iría de 1 a 10, a 100 o a 500 y que no tendrías que transformar en a b c, sino que le das fila 1 columna 1 y te entiende. Fin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He buscado pero no he encontrado documentación que explique más a
> detalle la diferencia entre las dos formas.

El primer lugar en el que debes buscar cuando tengas dudas es en la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en).

Realmente hay **cuatro formas** (no dos) de obtener rangos en Google Sheets. Expliquemos cada una desde la documentación, siguiendo el orden en tu pregunta:

### Primera forma

> #### [`getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangea1notation)
>
> Devuelve el rango especificado en notación A1 o notación R1C1.

Si lees [la documentación](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=es-419) donde se explica cada notación, ya vas teniendo respuesta a tu duda sobre cuándo es más útil una u otra:

> **Notación A1**
>
> Sintaxis que se usa para definir una celda o un rango de celdas con
> una string que contiene el nombre de la hoja y las coordenadas
> iniciales y finales de la celda mediante letras y números de fila.
> Este método es el más común y útil cuando se hace referencia a un
> rango de celdas absoluto.
>
> **Notación R1C1**
>
> Sintaxis que se usa para definir una celda o un rango de celdas con
> una string que contiene el nombre de la hoja y las coordenadas de
> celda de inicio y finalización mediante números de filas y números de
> columnas. Este método es menos común que la notación A1, pero puede
> ser útil cuando se hace referencia a un rango de celdas relacionado
> con la posición de una celda determinada.

### Segunda forma

> #### [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
>
> Devuelve el rango con la celda superior izquierda en las coordenadas
> dadas con el número dado de filas y columnas.

Sobre la utilidad de este método, podríamos pensar en un escenario donde recibes esas posiciones numéricas de un array por ejemplo, pasarías los valores numéricos sin más para obtener el rango, sin preocuparte de las letras de las celdas como ocurre en el método anterior.

Aparte de las dos formas anteriores, objeto de tu pregunta, `getRange()` tiene otras dos formas:

### Tercera forma

> #### [`getRange(row, column)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column)
>
> Devuelve el rango con la celda superior izquierda en las coordenadas
> dadas.

### Cuarta forma

> #### [`getRange(row, column, numRows)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)
>
> Devuelve el rango con la celda superior izquierda en las coordenadas
> dadas y con el número de filas dado.

Comment: Ya lei la documentacion, parece que en ingles viene completa, por alguna razon la documentacion en español de esa clase esta vacia.Es la que habia revisado primero.

Comment: @Serrot puede que sea un problema con la traducción de Google, o que esa parte aún no esté traducida. Cuando no veas nada, puedes pulsar en el botón **`Switch to English`** que aparece arriba a la derecha, así verás el contenido en inglés.